# Matlab: Error when dividing the covariance matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, covariance

I have an expression which is part of the log-likelihood expression for a Gaussian state space model

```
express = 
\sum_{t=2}^T (x(t) - (A*x(t-1)))^2/2*Q
```

where T = 5, the number of samples/observations; x is a 2 by T matrix; Q is the covariance matrix of the process noise initialized using `eye`

x =

```
0.7311   -1.7152    0.2476    3.6643   -1.2870
0.4360    0.3554    0.1981    0.4168    0.2643
```

A =

```
0.1950   -0.9500
1.0000         0
```

Q =

```
 1     0
 0     1
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error using  / 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
```

This is how I have implemented:

```
numerator =  sum((x(:,2:T)-(A*x(:,1:(T-1)))).^2)
```

numerator =

```
2.0732    3.0349    3.2291    1.5365

express = numerator / diag(2*diag(Q))
```

Should I be taking the diagonal or determinant of `Q`? Please help in correcting this part. Thank you.

Comment: You can't divide matrices or vectors. I think you want element-by-element division, so try `./`.

Comment: I did the dot divide earlier. And it returned the same error :  >> numerator./(2*diag(Q))
Error using  ./ 
Matrix dimensions must agree.  Even, without using diagonal, I get the same error

Comment: That means that `numerator` and `2*diag(Q))` are different sizes. Work out what you are trying to achieve then write the code. It may be possible to make the code work but not be doing the right algorithm.

Comment: @David: I am trying to implement the log-likelihood expression Eq(7) from the paper, Parameter Estimation for Linear Dynamical Systems (1996)  http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.55.5997 . The first 2 expression involving R and log R work fine. The problem comes when I am working with Q.

Comment: I'm not seeing any division by `Q` in the equation, because you cannot divide matrices. `Q^{-1}` is NOT `1/Q`, it is the inverse of the matrix `Q`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are squaring the term too early.  The (') symbol means you need to take the complex conjugate of the term before multiplying it by the inverse of Q and then the term again.  I believe you are trying to calculate this

[image: formula]

in which case the term you want to sum over is the following,

```
term = x(:,2:T)-(A*x(:,1:(T-1));
result = term' * inv(Q) * term
```

the result of which is a 4x4 matrix.  You can then sum this (over both directions I presume).  From the (7) in the [link](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=5C049708BC45EA13E000751C31425B3C?doi=10.1.1.55.5997&rep=rep1&type=pdf) you mention, you should need to follow this same procedure three times (for R, Q, and V).

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. The error is not there anymore. However, I  have  a few conceptual questions, can you please clarify, if possible? (A) I am getting this result for the expression  Eq(7) -13.4165 Inf; Inf -13.4165. will the evaluation of log-likelihood expression in Eq(7) be a square matrix with off diagonals being infinity? (B) Can you mention what is the p, and k terms in the last part of the expression? Appreciate your insights and clarifications.

Comment: @SKM, I would need to brush up on the details of math behind what you are doing to provide the further help you are asking.  I recommend asking on the math stackexchange where they are likely much more familiar with the material: http://math.stackexchange.com/